# Missing reminders

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, icloud, reminders

After upgrading all my devices I have the following situation regarding iCloud reminders:

- Reminders are correctly synced among macs (Catalina). I can add reminders, mark them as completed and the changes are shown on all the machines.
- Reminders are correctly synced to one iPad on one iPhone (both lists are shown and changes are synced)
- Reminders are not complete on one iPhone and one iPad

  - Instead of my two lists I see two “new list”s
  - One of the is empty (should not)
  - The other one shows just one element (which exist in the original lists but is not the only one)
- www.icloud.com shows me an empty window (but the lists exist are are working on four devices)

What I tried

- Restarting
- Logging out of iCloud and logging in
- Removing the reminders sync (delete the local storage) and enabling it again
- Completely reinstalling the non-working iPad and iPhone restoring from backup (after a little while the two empty lists appeared again)

What can I try next?

**Edit**

- I also noticed that Reminders is eating up a lot of battery on the iPad
- I also allowed a lot of time to sync among the different tries (even days)
- I deleted the app (with the data) an reinstalled it